# server restart daemon cannot bind socket, address already in use, manual restart daemon ok

Tags: sockets, memory-address

in Solaris 10, when server restart, the backup daemon (tina_daemon) does not work properly when calling for another executable to shutdown the application services.

however, when manually restart the backup daemon, the calling for the executable works fine.

I found the following lines in the log-file:

```
8|9|tina_daemon|780|1|3|1373964994|1373964994|10739|tina_daemon_1|<host name deleted>|~|root|~|backup_poc_tina|backup-poc|Event handler daemon started|0|~|~|~|~|~|~|
8|9|tina_daemon|880|256|3|1373964994|1373964994|10739|tina_daemon_1|<host name deleted>|~|root|~|backup_poc_tina|backup-poc|Service opened, host "<host name deleted>", Time Navigator Enterprise Edition Version 4.2.8.8 P4680|0|~|~|~|~|~|~|
8|14|TNUnixSocketImpl::initNetServiceTcp|11|1|1|1373965001|1373965001|10963|tina_daemon_1|<host name deleted>|~|root|~|backup_poc_tina|backup-poc|Unable to bind 5 socket, retos=125 "Address already in use"|0|~|~|~|~|~|~|
8|14|vos_init_net_service_tcp|1|1|4|1373965001|1373965001|10963|tina_daemon_1|<host name deleted>|~|root|~|backup_poc_tina|backup-poc|Unable to initialize network service of TCP type, retex=TN_ERR_CONFLICT_RESS (conflict in access to the same resource)|0|~|~|~|~|~|~|
```

is it a potential that not enough share memory? since the tina_daemon use 2 ports which already define in the /etc/services

I feel very weird since when manually using root to restart the tina_daemon, everything works fine. When server restart with the startup script (which i changed to similar to manul restart), it does not work well for calling another executable to shutdown the application. It shutdown the application half way, and cause the application hang (and ultimate need to restart the application)